# What is wrong with my json format, jsonlint throws error?

Tags: json

Please help me find the error, Json lint throws this error

```
{
    "checkRid": "ri.data-health.lava-catalog.check.50418784-00c5-46e0-96ad-e806e24190a4",
    "version": 2,
    "checkName": "schemaComparison",
    "groups": [],
    "checkIntent": null,
    "participants": {
        "datasetRid": "ri.foundry.lava-catalog.dataset.3b31fb14-2ba2-446c-b811-5c4a808ba710",
        "branchId": "master",
        "columnNames": []
    },
    "subjects": [],
    "validations": {
        "type": "schemaComparison",
        "schemaComparison": {
            "severity": "MODERATE",
            "schemaInfo": {
                "columns": {
                    "name": "code",
                    "columnType": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "columnType": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "columnType": "STRING"
                }
            },
            "schemaComparisonType": "EXACT_MATCH_UNORDERED_COLUMNS"
        }
    },
    "schedule": null,
    "autoResolutionConfiguration": null,
    "issueConfiguration": null,
    "isContractCheck": false,
    "attribution": {
        "userId": "8be575d6-eb3b-4fec-bd5e-81fc7c4ee8b0",
        "lastUpdated": "2021-02-18T09:51:52.934376Z"
    }
}
```

**the error shown as:**

> Error: Parse error on line 21:
> ..."STRING"             },              {                   "name": "name
> ---------------------^
> Expecting 'STRING', got '{'

Comment: Why do you put some unnamed element after that `columns` element?

Comment: Also, how is this related to programming?

Comment: This is response form an rest api, need to parse it

Comment: That API response is not valid JSON, so you should ask the maintainer of that API to send proper data

Comment: finally used regex to make "columns" and "validations"  to  a list. now everything works fine. able to parse and collect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally used regex to make "columns" and "validations" to a list. now everything works fine. able to parse and collect data.

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** did you do to fix that problem? Why not ask the maintainer of that API to provide a correct repoonse?

Answer (score 1):

There are some key's missing:
[image]

You can use several online tools to validate your json like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/